# Accessing Remote files using HTTP from a web application

Tags: java

we have a requirement where all file (text , image , PDF etc) uploaded in the Server1. Now we have a Java web application running in a different server (Server 2) which has to read these files and show it in the GUI.

FTP is blocked in web application server. So i am thinking of using HTTP. 
The files in Server1 is not distributed .i.e not inside any ear or war.
I managed to get the code to read a file from HTTP.

My question is
- How do i access this file through HTTP when these files are not distributed
- When i write a code accessing the file like http://server1:port1/location of file , its says file not found . 
- how do i expose these files , so that i can access it via HTTP from my web application

Answer (score 0):

That means, you want to download the content of the file. 
Well at very first, open up a browser. Enter http://server1:port1/FILE_PATH .
what do you get as a response ?

Second, if you get "FILE NOT FOUND" then you need to configure a virtual path mapped to real path in server1. After that, try the URL from browser again. When it works,

```
URL website = new URL("http://server1/file_location");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file_name");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

will help you to download the file to your local machine.

Comment: File is not accesible  from browser .. How do i add virtual path ?

Comment: What server are you using for listing the files ? Tomcat container ? Apache HTTP ? `Alias /myproject "C:/path/to/my/project"
<Directory "C:/path/to/my/project">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>`

Comment: Server 1 - Weblogic Container  contains files outside the ear    Server 2 -  weblogic container which will read files in server1.

Comment: Check this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1039396

Comment: And also this would be helpful http://connectionserver.blogspot.com.tr/2009/05/listing-directories-simple-weblogic.html